# Difference between SN75451 and conventional gate?

Tags: current, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, texas-instruments

I use a board where the designers uses a SN75451 chip. It is a dual AND gate chip with open collector output.

I am quite surprised as normally the 74xx09 would be used in order to implement AND gate with open collector output. Why in the world would we want to use a different chip?

It seems like LEDs can be lit directly from the chip so is it simply because it can drive a lot of current ? If so, why use this chips instead of a discrete transistor ?

Comment: Banner line title: "Dual-Peripheral Drivers for High-Current, High-Speed Switching"

Comment: Voting to close because this question is asking about the *use* of electronic devices, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Please do not change the question on the fly. It makes existing answers invalid and helps no-one. If you need to correct or add more, add it to the end of the question as an edit.

Comment: @sstobbe Banner lines such as "high-current" or "high-speed" does not mean anything if they don't say against which currents or speed they are comparatively "high".

Answer (score 3):

Seriously...

The 451 is a dual open collector AND driver IC not a quad AND gate.

[image]

It can handle 400mA continuous. As you suspect, it is good for driving heavier loads at higher voltages like LEDs, small motors etc.

**EDIT:** Since you chose fit to change your question....

> why use this chips instead of a discrete transistor

You could use discrete transistors, but that would be more real-estate to add two transistors than one device. Having said that, my guess is sales on this particular device were below engineering's expectations.

Comment: The 74xx09 is not a NAND gate, it is a quad AND gate

Comment: @DerStrom8 lol picky picky... corrected.

Comment: @DerStrom8 It was a 74xx00 NAND gate.. why the OP  changed the original question I don't know...